# casting MapValue to double and multiply to double in dart

Tags: dart

Iam new to dart I want a Make table of food program which take an input from user for each food and how much they want  but i have an problem with multiply `listOfFood[name]` with `count` which both of them double is there any way to solve this  ?

```
  double name , count ;
  Map<String , dynamic> listOfFood  = {

    'bacon' :'4.2',
    
    'salad' :'3.5',
    
    'cheaken'  :'5.6',
    
    'Goatmeat' :'6.9',
    
    'fish' : '6.5',
    

  };
  Map<int , dynamic> food = {

     1 : listOfFood ['bacon']
    ,2 : listOfFood ['salad']
    ,3 : listOfFood ['cheaken']
    ,4 : listOfFood ['Goatmeat']
    ,5 : listOfFood ['fish']
  };
  stdout.write('please Choose your product \n ${listOfFood}');

 
name = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

count = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
double result = (food[name]) * count;
print(result);


}
```

Comment: Hint: `'4.00'` isn't a double.

Comment: To make it easier  to read your code, please run `dart format <file>` on it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot coerce a String that looks like a number to a `double` in Dart.

Dart has strong typing even when you declare a variable `dynamic`.

In your case, you're taking the value from `listOfFood` (not a `List`, use a better name like `priceByFoodName`), which is always a String (despite the Map having dynamic values) and multiplying that with a `double` which can't work.

You should ask yourself why are the prices Strings?

If you want to use them as numbers, just make them numbers.

Also, you don't need `dynamic` at all. Use types! If you had done that the compiler would've told you right away what the problem was before you even ran the code. That's why types exist.

To solve the problem quickly... this line:

```
double result = (food[name]) * count;
```

Should be changed to:

```
double result = double.parse(food[name]!) * count;
```

But you should probably change your code quite a bit to handle errors, use appropriate types, stop ignoring nulls etc.

Comment: I change a lot but Still have an same Erorr , Oh no! i miss to put an `\n` between two inputs thanks brothers  and its work now